# Ordering two separate classes

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How would one go about ordering two different classes? So say there's Class1 and Class2 that both have the same kind of field, how would I do (Class1 + Class2).asc(:field)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way, for example

```
 class A
    attr_accessor :f1
 end

 class B
    attr_accessor :f1
 end

 a=A.new
 a.f1="a"

 b=B.new
 b.f1="b"

 arr = []
 arr << b << a
=> [#<B:0x6153e0c0 @f1="b">, #<A:0x55a517bd @f1="a">]
```

and you can sort by

```
arr.sort_by(&:f1)
=> [#<A:0x55a517bd @f1="a">, #<B:0x6153e0c0 @f1="b">]
```

is the short form of

```
arr.sort_by {|x| x.f1}
```

even you can use sort method to specify asc,desc

```
>> arr.sort{|x,y| x.f1 <=> y.f1}
=> [#<A:0x55a517bd @f1="a">, #<B:0x6153e0c0 @f1="b">]
>> arr.sort{|x,y| y.f1 <=> x.f1}
=> [#<B:0x6153e0c0 @f1="b">, #<A:0x55a517bd @f1="a">]
```

hope this helps